HTMLElement: hidden property
I have a HTML UL element that I want to hide with the .hidden property dynamically with JavaScript. Problem is, when there is a CSS rule: display: block on the element, the hidden property does not work.


document.getElementById('myid').hidden = true;
#myid {
  display: block;
}
<div id="myid">Lorem ipsum</div>



The browser adds the hidden property to the element correctly, but the element does not hide because display: block is set.
I expected that JavaScript will override the CSS. What use is then to have the hidden property?
Why is this? and is this a bug?

It looks like display: block takes precedence, since removing it hides the element.

What use? If you don't have the CSS style you can use the hidden property.

MDN: elements styled display: block will be displayed despite the hidden attribute's presence.

So it is not of much use and unreliable in dynamic cases where I do not know what to expect.

This is because hidden is related to visibility property. However, there is also the display property. Your class sets display property to block and that is why it contradicts with visibility.
You can toggle CSS classes if you want to show/hide entire element:
function toggle(){
  const div = document.getElementById('myid');
  div.classList.toggle("is-shown");
  div.classList.toggle("is-hidden");
}

CSS classes:
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.is-shown {
    display: block;
}    

HTML:
<div id="myid" class="is-shown">Lorem ipsum</div>

If you want to toggle only visibility you may prefer CSS classes:
.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
}


You need a CSS rule [hidden] {display:none!important;}. Something like this.


function toggle(){
var elem=document.getElementById('myid');
elem.hidden = !elem.hidden;
}
#myid {
  display: block;
}
[hidden]{
display:none!important;
}
<div id="myid">Lorem ipsum</div>
<button type="button" onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>



In fact, the question is about CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) hierarchy. See comprehensive description for example at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

That is interesting, didn't know that was possible.
